# How to get selected table cells background colour?

Tags: jquery, html, css-tables

I have a table which displays information. One of the columns in the table is a notes column. On this notes column I've created a tool tip using some CSS and Jquery. The problem I'm having is that when I hover over the cell, it displays the tool tip correctly, however it wipes the colour (turns white) from the cell after moving the mouse away. I want it to retain its colour after the mouse it moved away, but I'm not sure how.

Current code for the tool tip event (each notes cell has the note class):

```
$('.note').hover(
       function (event) {
           $(event.target).css({
               "white-space": "normal",
               "text-overflow": "clip",
               "background-color": "#eeeeee",
               "max-width": "200px",
               "position": "absolute"
           });
       }, function (event) {
           $(event.target).css({
               "white-space": "nowrap",
               "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
               "background-color": "transparent",
               "max-width": "200px",
               "position": "static"
           });
       }
   );
```

Comment: no problem to do the solution on css?

Comment: That is to be expected as your code adds that inline css to the element after cursor leaves the element. You should just use pure css and :hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use pure `css` for this purpose,

```
.note:hover {
    white-space: normal;
    text-overflow: clip;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    max-width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

In this case, elements will retain the background color and other properties after hover.

Comment: Note that for non-link elements you lose support for the effect of IE6 by doing so ( http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3Ahover )

Comment: I have taken your advice on using pure css. Now when I hover over it retains the bg colour correctly, although it only shows the background colour of the tool tip every even number cell now :S? So for example the first cell seems to show a transparent tool tip background, the second displays correctly, ect... thanks for your time!

Comment: @MimiLauren Can you share the html?

Comment: I've found the problem. I'm using the Jquery 'table-stripe' class on my table, and it seems to be interfering with the hover css for some reason. Any advice?

Comment: where should I post it? I've built my table using Javascript

Comment: You can change the css selector like this #idoftable tr{ }